# Multiple where conditions in EF using Lambda expressions

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I'm using entity framework and Linq Querable, I want to select some data using a multiple where clause.

In my DB, i have in one field that may have multiple ids `FieldOfInterestID`, separated by ";" (I know, I know, but it's to late to do something), or just one id, that means that the comma won't be present

I want to split the string with the ";" separator, and than all those ids to use them in my where clause.

My code looks something like this:

```
await ctx.Customer.AsNoTracking()
    .Where(e => e.UserId == userId)
    .Select(e => new UserDTO {
        FieldsOfStudy = ctx.Terms.Where(t => {
            if (!e.FieldOfInterestID.Contains(";") && t.TermId.ToString() == e.FieldOfInterestID)
                return true;
            else if (e.FieldOfInterestID.Contains(";")

            {
                string fieldOfInterestIds = e.FieldOfInterestID.Split(";");
                foreach (string fieldOfInterestID in fieldOfInterestIds)
                {
                    if (t.TermId.ToString() == e.FieldOfInterestID)
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;
                }
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
    })
    .ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

My current "error" is `not all code paths return a value...`

How can I use string[] in my where clause better?

Comment: Your `foreach()` will run 0 or 1 times. Is that what you intended?  The 0 times case is the cause for this error, but what do you really want to happen for 2 or more elements?

Comment: @HenkHolterman, no i did not intend that :)

Comment: You need [a rubber duck](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current error is because of this branch:

```
foreach (string fieldOfInterestID in fieldOfInterestIds)
{
    if (t.TermId.ToString() == e.FieldOfInterestID)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

From the compiler perspective, the body of the `foreach` may not be entered, hence `not all code paths return a value...`.

You can fix it by moving the `return false;` outside the body:

```
foreach (string fieldOfInterestID in fieldOfInterestIds)
{
    if (t.TermId.ToString() == e.FieldOfInterestID)
        return true;
}
return false;
```

This will fix the compiler error, but will not solve the problem. Once you run it you'll find that LINQ to Entities does not support lambda expressions with body (`=> { ... }`), and also `string.Split` method.

The real solution requires a different criteria - instead of unsupported

```
e.FieldOfInterestID.Split(";").Contains(t.TermId.ToString())
```

the opposite but supported (uses string concatenation and `string.Contains`)

```
(";" + e.FieldOfInterestID + ";").Contains(";" + t.TermId + ";")
```

Enclosing both strings with `;` is needed to correctly handle first, intermediate and last tokens.

The final query could be like this:

```
var query = ctx.Customer.AsNoTracking()
    .Where(e => e.UserId == userId)
    .Select(e => new UserDTO
    {
        FieldsOfStudy = ctx.Terms
            .Where(t => (";" + e.FieldOfInterestID + ";").Contains(";" + t.TermId + ";"))
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This line seems wrong to me:

`string fieldOfInterestIds = e.FieldOfInterestID.Split(";");`

I would change it to:

`string[] fieldOfInterestIds = e.FieldOfInterestID.Split(";");`

Also I would simplify the code a little:

`ctx.Terms.Where(t => return e.FieldOfInterestID.Split(";").Contains(t.TermId.ToString()));`

If the string does not contain the `;`characters it returns a string[] with one item

Comment: Valid remakrks but nothing related to "not all code paths return a value"

Comment: If I'm using .contains , i guess i don't need need the Split anymore, right ?

Comment: @SGN ' i guess i don't need need the Split anymore' It depends on the TermId values.
`"135".Contains("3")` would return `true`. Similar to `String.IndexOf`
`"135;12".Split(";").Contains("3")` would return `false`
`"135;12".Split(";").Contains("12")` would return `true`